# Exception when creating database in sdCard using greenDAO library

Tags: java, android, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm trying to create db in sdcard using greenDAO but I am getting an exception.
Here I have attached the snippet code for DatabaseManager.java and DAOMaster.java file. Please have a look and give me your suggestions. Thank you. :)

DatabaseManager.java

```
public class DatabaseManager implements  IDatabaseManager,AsyncOperationListener {

    /**
     * Class tag. Used for debug.
     */
    private static final String TAG = DatabaseManager.class.getCanonicalName();
    /**
     * Instance of DatabaseManager
     */
    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    /**
     * The Android Activity reference for access to DatabaseManager.
     */
    private Context context;
    private DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DaoMaster daoMaster;
    private DaoSession daoSession;
    private AsyncSession asyncSession;
    private List<AsyncOperation> completedOperations;

    /**
     * Constructs a new DatabaseManager with the specified arguments.
     *
     * @param context The Android {@link android.content.Context}.
     */
    public DatabaseManager(final Context context) {

        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/MobInvSuit/mis");
        path.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this.context, path.getAbsolutePath(), null);
        database=helper.getWritableDatabase();

        daoMaster=new DaoMaster(database);
      //  this.context = context;
     //   mHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this.context, "sample-database", null);
        completedOperations = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<AsyncOperation>();
    }

    /**
     * @param context The Android {@link android.content.Context}.
     * @return this.instance
     */
    public static DatabaseManager getInstance(Context context) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
        completedOperations.add(operation);
    }

    private void assertWaitForCompletion1Sec() {
        asyncSession.waitForCompletion(1000);
        asyncSession.isCompleted();
    }

    /**
     * Query for readable DB
     */
    public void openReadableDb() throws SQLiteException {
        database = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(database);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
        asyncSession = daoSession.startAsyncSession();
        asyncSession.setListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Query for writable DB
     */
    public void openWritableDb() throws SQLiteException {
        database = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(database);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
        asyncSession = daoSession.startAsyncSession();
        asyncSession.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void closeDbConnections() {
        if (daoSession != null) {
            daoSession.clear();
            daoSession = null;
        }
        if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            database.close();
        }
        if (mHelper != null) {
            mHelper.close();
            mHelper = null;
        }
        if (instance != null) {
            instance = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void dropDatabase() {
        try {
            openWritableDb();
            DaoMaster.dropAllTables(database, true); // drops all tables
            mHelper.onCreate(database);              // creates the tables
            asyncSession.deleteAll(Setting.class);    // clear all elements from a table

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

DAOMaster.java

```
package com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch.dao;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDaoMaster;
import de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeType;

import com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch.dao.SettingDao;
import com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch.dao.UserDao;

// THIS CODE IS GENERATED BY greenDAO, DO NOT EDIT.
/** 
 * Master of DAO (schema version 1): knows all DAOs.
*/
public class DaoMaster extends AbstractDaoMaster {
    public static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

    /** Creates underlying database table using DAOs. */
    public static void createAllTables(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
        SettingDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
        UserDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
    }

    /** Drops underlying database table using DAOs. */
    public static void dropAllTables(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifExists) {
        SettingDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
        UserDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
    }

    public static abstract class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public OpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, name, factory, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Creating tables for schema version " + SCHEMA_VERSION);
            createAllTables(db, false);
        }
    }

    /** WARNING: Drops all table on Upgrade! Use only during development. */
    public static class DevOpenHelper extends OpenHelper {
        public DevOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, name, factory);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by dropping all tables");
            dropAllTables(db, true);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DaoMaster(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super(db, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        registerDaoClass(SettingDao.class);
        registerDaoClass(UserDao.class);
    }

    public DaoSession newSession() {
        return new DaoSession(db, IdentityScopeType.Session, daoConfigMap);
    }

    public DaoSession newSession(IdentityScopeType type) {
        return new DaoSession(db, type, daoConfigMap);
    }

}
```

Exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch, PID: 30820
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch/com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch.Login}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open databaseat android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cisystem3.mobiledeliveryndispatch">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: And the exception is....? attach the stacktrace please

Comment: Exception attached...Saying " Could not open database" @elefasGR

Comment: And your android manifest file please

Comment: I believe it is working when i'm not specifing any sdcard path. @elefasGR

Comment: Exception coming at this line database=helper.getWritableDatabase();@elefasGR

Comment: Does the path on your sdcard exists and what is the filename of the database you are trying to open?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126723/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-elefasgr).